# What is the relationship between the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and indefinite integrals?

Tags: calculus

I just want to clarify a few facts (this may be a very stupid question, but I seem to be confused).

So the first part of the FTC states:

> Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed
>   interval $[a, b]$. Let $F$ be the function defined, for all $x$ in
>   $[a, b]$, by
>
> $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$$
>
> Then, $F$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on the open
>   interval $(a, b)$, and
>
> $$F'(x) = f(x)$$
>
> for all $x$ in $(a, b)$.

Now my first question is what's the difference between writing the indefinite integral $\int f(x) dx$ and $\int_a^x f(t) dt$? To demonstrate, say $f(x) = x^2$, then from high school, the notation $\int x^2 dx = \frac{x^3}{3} + C$ for some constant of integration. But, using the FTC, we also have $\int_a^x t^2 dt = \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{a^3}{3}$, now since $-\frac{a^3}{3}$ is a constant, let $C = -\frac{a^3}{3}$ and we have the same answer. So do both expressions $\int f(x) dx$ and $\int_a^x f(t) dt$ provide the GENERAL antiderivative? i.e., with the constant of integration included? Is it correct to say $\int f(x) dx=\int_a^x f(t) dt$?

My second question is related to this but in a differential equations context. Define $m(t) = \int_0^t \lambda(u) du$ where $\lambda(t)$ is a continuous function for $t \ge 0$. Now solve the ODE:

$y'(t) = -y(t)\lambda(t)$ where $y(t) > 0$ for all $t \ge 0$.

So we have: $y'(t)/y(t) = -\lambda(t) \implies \int y'(t)/y(t) dt = -\int \lambda(t) dt \implies \ln[y(t)] + C_1 = -\int_0^t \lambda(u) du  \implies  \ln[y(t)] + C_1 = -m(t) + C_2 $

Now is $m(t)$ the general antiderivative or just a particular one? Because if it's the general one then there is no need for me to write $C_2$ since $C_2$ is "absorbed" in $m(t)$ right? And is it right to replace $\int \lambda(t) dt$  with $\int_0^t \lambda(u) du$?

Comment: For the first, no.  $\int_a^x{f(x)dx}$ is an actual function, while $\int{f(x)dx}$ is technically a family of functions (since the constant of integration is arbitrary).

Comment: So basically $\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is only a particular antiderivative of $f(x)$ right? Thus, if I write $\int_a^x f(t) dt + C$, then this would be the entire family of antiderivatives of $f(x)$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that appears correct.